# Tabs labeled "Design" and "Text" missing in the layout editor in Android Studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, editor

In Android Studio 3.6.1, I no longer see the tabs labeled "Design" and "Text" that used to be in the layout editor below the Component Tree, which could be used to switch between xml code and the design view. See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Add your code not just a bunch of error messages.

Comment: Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp7LY.png

Comment: `package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}`

Comment: If you mean edit xml in text it is in the corner. The 3 icons there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is. In the top right corner.

[image: solution]

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off topic/bad questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572)

Comment: I don't understand why this is an off-topic or bad question. It's a legitimate question since this new version of Android Studio changed the layout considerably (I personally liked it better before, BTW). Thanks, @Nishant; it helped me find the way to edit xml directly.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree even I couldn't find a few things in the newer version of Android Studio at first. Things that are obvious to some people might not be so obvious to all.